# Get key with condition in Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
 if ($totalModuletest>0){
     if (in_array(1, $modValArr, true)){
         echo "1.13 found with strict check\n";
      }
 }
 else{
      $aVal = 0;
 }
```

By using print_r($modValArr);

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1[5])
```

I want to know any value exist greater than zero in this array. If it exists I need its key. The result I need is 4.

How is this possible in PHP?

Comment: 1. How does your array structure looks like? 2.So you want to filter all values out which are greater than 0 and then get the keys from all these values?

Comment: @Sona but within your array no value is greater than `0`

Comment: In this example at the end `$modValArr` is exactly equal to `$moduleArr` - is there a reason you are copying it like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just filter all values below 0 out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then just get the keys with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php))

```
<?php

    $arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ""];
    $result = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function($v){
        return $v > 0;
    }));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 )
```

Comment: Nice, but no need for the function.  `array_filter` will filter out 0, '', null, false.

Comment: @AbraCadaver you're right, but I think OP wants to change the number(X) `$v > X` as he wants it to have, so it wouldn't work with `$v > 3` or so that's why I wrote it that way from the start

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$yourarray=array(0,0,2,0,4,1);
//array_filter used to remove 0,null,empty array.so you will get non empty or grater then 0 value of array
$newvalue=array_filter($yourarray);

foreach($newvalue as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "value:".$value;
 echo "Key:".$key;
}
```

Comment: This is a string and NOT an array!

Comment: I have posted example array

Comment: And now it's even worse, because this will throw you a fatal error!

Answer (score 0):

To find any value greater than zero:

```
function find_keys_greater_than(Array $input_array, $val_to_check = 0){
    $keys_greater_than = [];    
    foreach ($input_array as $key => $value){
        if ($value > $val_to_check){
            $keys_greater_than[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $keys_greater_than;
}
```

E.g.

```
$input_array=[0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0];
$keys_greater_than_zero = find_keys_greater_than($input_array, 0);
// output: [2, 4]
```

You can change the value of `$val_to_check` to alter your threshold.